# Nesting COUNT in statement with JOIN

Tags: mysql

Really trying to figure out, why SQL query doesnt go through. I assume the structure is a bit wrong, but cant figure out where exactly. The references to tables are all correct.

```
SELECT tap_questionnaires.id, 
   tap_questionnaires.NAME, 
   tap_questionnaires.active, 
   tap_useranswers_ip.questionnaire_id, 
   Count(tap_useranswers_ip.ip) 
FROM   tap_questionnaires 
       LEFT JOIN tap_useranswers_ip 
              ON tap_questionnaires.id = tap_useranswers_ip.questionnaire_id 
WHERE  author_email = admin@admin.com
```

Comment: Delimiting strings with quotes usually helps, as does looking at the actual errors resulting from trying to execute a bad query.

Comment: shouldn't the author_email literal be quoted?

Comment: Oh god, im so embarrased right now... Thanks guys and sorry for being so bad, whole day of coding got me tired

Answer (score 0):

If you use count you need to use group by for the other columns in your select clause.

```
SELECT TAP_questionnaires.id, TAP_questionnaires.name, TAP_questionnaires.active, TAP_useranswers_ip.questionnaire_id, COUNT(TAP_useranswers_ip.ip) FROM TAP_questionnaires LEFT JOIN TAP_useranswers_ip on TAP_questionnaires.id=TAP_useranswers_ip.questionnaire_id WHERE author_email="admin@admin.com"
group by TAP_questionnaires.id, TAP_questionnaires.active
```

I think TAP_questionnaires.name it's not necessary because I suppose it depends on TAP_questionnaires.id. TAP_useranswers_ip.questionnaire_id is the same value as TAP_questionnaires.id

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this version is clearer:

```
SELECT q.id, q.name, q.active,  COUNT(a.ip)
FROM TAP_questionnaires q LEFT JOIN
     TAP_useranswers_ip a
     ON on q.id = a.questionnaire_id
WHERE author_email = 'admin@admin.com'
GROUP BY q.id, q.name, q.active;
```

Notes:

- You need a `GROUP BY`.
- You need single quotes around the string constant.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- There is no reason to include `a.questionnaire_id`.  You already have q.id.

Comment: This actually worked like a charm. Realised i need group by after a couple of tries. Thanks!